# How to get a "list" with complex nodes available on other pages

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms, global, xmlnode

I use xamarin.forms and need to create a long list of data that I read from an XML-file. (the XML is included in the APK as an "asset"). That list is read once and shall be used (read-only) throughout the app. The List contains the base data of the world I am working in. Each node of the list has 6 elements.

I have chosen to put the code for that in MainActivity.cs with the rationale that I can then have 
the list available globally (That appears to be an incorrect assumption). The App reads the XML (all 6 Data fields per list item) and the data arrives just fine in a list called **"_Proben"**. 
My fundamental problem is that the list created is NOT available in other pages of the App.
(Attempts to apply a Singleton class approach didn´t work for me. The advice given was often not concrete enough, because I need to know where in Xamarin I need to embed the code and what I need to "using" where. Abstract advice didn´t help me, code without placeholders works best for me.)
Then I tried to move to code away from MainActivity.cs to a specific page "page1.xaml.cs" with the intention to create the list at least in that local environment (still not global, but at least I can downselect there).
I can not get it to run the code in page1.xaml.cs: It will not accept the AssetManager and gives me the error "*CS0246 the type or namespace "AssetManager" could not be found...*"

I am lost.

Q1) What do I need to do, to run the code below in page1.xaml.cs ? (code that works well in MainActivity.cs)

Q2) even better:  How could I make that list (with 6 elements per entry) globally read-accessible?

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    // Liste erstellen aller Proben
    public static List<ProbenKlasse> _Proben = new List<ProbenKlasse>();protected override     
    void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        Int16 i = 0;       
        // open the file from the asset folder
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("ProbenDB2.xml"));
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(sr);
        // now initializing the reader 
        XmlNodeReader nodeRead = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
        XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/ProbenDS/Probe");
        // Beginn reading the XML
        i = 0; // start counting how many data sets were in the XML
        String text1;  // just data containers for the 6 data fields of each entry in the list
        String text2;  // just data containers for the 6 data fields of each entry in the list
        Int16 c1; // just data containers for the 6 data fields of each entry in the list
        Int16 c2; // just data containers for the 6 data fields of each entry in the list
        Int16 c3; // just data containers for the 6 data fields of each entry in the list
        Int16 c4; // just data containers for the 6 data fields of each entry in the list
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            ProbenKlasse aktprob = new ProbenKlasse(); 
            text1 =              xn["Titel"].InnerText;       aktprob.Titel = text1;
            c1 = Convert.ToInt16(xn["Probentyp"].InnerText);  aktprob.Probentyp = c1;
            c2 = Convert.ToInt16(xn["Wurf1"].InnerText);      aktprob.Wurf1 = c2;
            c3 = Convert.ToInt16(xn["Wurf2"].InnerText);      aktprob.Wurf2 = c3;
            c4 = Convert.ToInt16(xn["Wurf3"].InnerText);      aktprob.Wurf3 = c4;
            text2 =              xn["Beschreibung"].InnerText; aktprob.Beschreibung = text2;
            _Proben.Add(aktprob); // adding the newly read data set to the list
            i = ++i;
        }
        GlobalVariables.AnzProben = i;  // letting the app know how many data sets we have
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess that you want to load xml file to get data, then using this data in the ContentPage, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can use  DependencyService in Xamarin.forms,

Here is the **DependencyService**, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

I do one sample about using DependencyService to get xml file from Android to Forms, you can take a look:

Firstly, create interface in Forms:

```
public interface IClick
{

    string GetContent();
}
```

ContentPage :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content = DependencyService.Get<IClick>().GetContent();
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
   [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]
 namespace App3.Droid
 {
   [Activity(Label = "App3", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity,IClick
{
    public string GetContent()
    {
        string content="";
        AssetManager asset = Application.Context.Assets;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(asset.Open("note.xml")))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return content;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
  }
 }
```